# Are we the only SE with challenges?

Tags: discussion

This is a simple question, perhaps better asked elsewhere, but I'm quite curious:

**Besides [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), is PPCG the only SE site whose questions are *challenges* rather than *appeals*?**

Pretty much every other SE site has questions that are asked because the questioner is honestly confused or uncertain or at least curious about something. But here at PPCG, answers do not really answer anything, they just follow a spec to produce something that was already expected (though often in outstanding ways).

I've looked at many of the other [SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), but not all, and I'm not a frequenter on any of them but PPCG. Are there corners of other SE sites where challenges are the norm rather than appeals for help?

Comment: I've *at least* visited basically all the SE sites, and haven't seen anything similar (except Puzzling, which you excluded). If it's out there, it's being well hidden.

Comment: Note that even for Puzzling, questions are real questions (specifically, puzzles) that the person who posts them have. Sure, you can post a puzzle that you already know an answer to, but you can self-answer questions on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: The short answer is no. The closest thing I can think of are the questions tagged [fun](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun?sort=votes&pageSize=15) on [Tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), which is still very different.

Comment: On German language, we had [two](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15183/2594) [questions](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13654/2594) about finding a record in that language. In short, it was about finding the largest set of words which only differ by one vowel (with fixed position).

Comment: This has been suggested for Music SE. http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/666/9630 (BTW The top answer references isolated examples on the writing and Judaism sites.) I broadly agree with the answers, both of which state that questions orthogonal to the main purpose of the site wouldn't add and might detract. Questions about specific songs are actually off topic, so the OP's proposal for a contest to "harmonise a certain melody" would've got shot  down if he'd posted on the main site instead of Meta. Similarly, I think it's a good thing that Code-Golf is kept separate from Stack Overflow.

Comment: There may be one-off questions on the other sites, but I don't know of any others (except for puzzles), where it's virtually all the questions

Comment: Code Review is about appeals rather than challenges, but shares with us the peculiarity of being primarily (I'm not going to rehash recent-ish meta and chat discussions) about *doing* the thing named in site title rather than *learning about* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope! PPCG's the only Stack Exchange site that does this.

It's likely going to be the only one of its kind, too, since Stack Exchange typically only launches sites whose questions are practical problems people face.